# How much do i owe the IRS on Sept 15th for income received in September?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, california, state-income-tax

Sold a house at end of August.
Cap gains of about $240k to $375k (federal + California) income tax will be due.

How much should I pay Sept 15th, 2020?

Comment: If the house was sold "at the end of August", doesn't that mean the income was received in August? But your title says it is received in September. Which is it? This is important because if you are paying estimated taxes (rather than trying to increase your withholding) you would have to pay 3rd quarter estimated taxes, due Sep 15, for income received in August, but if the income is received in September, you would only have to pay 4th quarter estimated taxes for it, due Jan 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might not have to pay them anything until April 2021.

The key is to make sure that you meet the IRS safe-harbor rules. If you make sure that through withholding and quarterly payments you have submitted to the IRS 110% of last years taxes, then you skip any penalties and interest related to this big capital gain.

I did this the last time I sold a house. It was a rental, and I couldn't get a close estimate of the impact with depreciation, recapture, and capital gains. So I made sure I had enough withheld from my job to make the safe-harbor. Then I sent the balance the following April.

You will have to see what California requires.

Comment: I can't comment on accuracy of the source, but this says that California safe harbour rules don't apply with income > $1M, which may apply in the case of a house sale. https://www.nixonpeabody.com/en/ideas/blog/trusts-and-estates/2016/07/06/when-safe-harbor-isnt-safe--californias-exception-to-the-rule

Comment: I am under $1M.

Comment: "If you make sure that through withholding and quarterly payments you have submitted to the IRS 110% of last years taxes, then you skip any penalties and interest related to this big capital gain." If you make sure that withholding reaches the required 90% of this year/110% of last year level by the end of the year, you won't have a penalty. However, if your withholding does not reach that level, you must pay a sufficient amount of estimated taxes (calculated via one of several ways) by *each quarter's estimated tax deadline* in order to avoid a penalty.

Comment: (continued) If you paid an insufficient amount of estimated taxes in early quarters, you will have a penalty even if you have paid a sufficient amount of estimated taxes total by the end of the year.